# Java gzip - GZIPOutputStream not closing / compressing arbitrarily

Tags: java, gzip, gzipoutputstream

With the help of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351668/compression-and-decompression-of-string-data-in-java) I was able to write a `decompress()` and a `compress()` function. My programme receives data in gzipped form, inflates it, sometimes modifies it, then re-compresses it again and sends it along. After hours of headache and bug tracing, I was able to find out that **sometimes(!)**, the `GZIPOutputStream` that I use just won't close properly. I am able to flush it but after that, nothing happens. However, at other times, it simply works >.>

This is the code of my `compress()` method.

```
public static byte[] compress(String data) throws IOException {
    try (PipedInputStream pipedIn = new PipedInputStream();
            GZIPOutputStream compressor= new GZIPOutputStream(new PipedOutputStream(pipedIn))) {
        compressor.write(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        compressor.flush();
        compressor.close();

        // Sometimes does not reach this point.

        return IOUtils.toByteArray(pipedIn);
    }
}
```

For debugging purposes, I added a few System.Outs. The console output was as follows:

```
------------------------------------
Decompressing ...
compressed byte count:   628
uncompressed byte count: 1072
------------------------------------
Compressing ...
uncompressed byte count: 1072
compressed byte count:   628
------------------------------------
>>> That worked!
------------------------------------
Decompressing ...
compressed byte count:   526
uncompressed byte count: 2629
------------------------------------
uncompressed byte count: 2629
compressed byte count:   526
------------------------------------
>>> That worked!
------------------------------------
Decompressing ...
compressed byte count:   1888
uncompressed byte count: 6254
------------------------------------
```

After that, nothing happens. Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably nothing wrong with your usage of GZIP streams; rather it is the way you use the Piped streams. These are meant for interthread communication and will block when you use them your way.

Instead use a `ByteArrayOutptuStream` to capture the output.

Comment: Could you give me a short example of how to do that? I wanted to do it in the first place, but I don't know how to get the data from the `OutputStream` into the `InputStream`.

*EDIT: if all fails, I will just open another thread to pipe the info.

Comment: [`ByteArrayOutputStream#toByteArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toByteArray()) is all you need.