# Play WS ZipException with GzipFilter and GZIPInputStream on client

Tags: java, scala, playframework, gzip

I have a client Scala Play app (2.1.x) that calls a local webservice over http. Response is JSON and gzipped when appropriate headers are set:

**Client**:

```
val responsePromise = WS.url(url).withHeaders(("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")).get
val response = Await.result(responsePromise, 30 seconds)
val x = GZIPCompression.decompress(response.body.getBytes("UTF-8"))
```

**Server**:

On the server I use the filter `play.filters.gzip.GzipFilter` for the compressing, from within a(nother) Play app (2.4.x)

**Problem**:

When receiving the response on the client side, it throws a `ZipException: Not in GZIP format` when passing `response.body.getBytes("UTF-8")` into the constructor of `GZIPInputStream`:

```
class GZIPCompression {
  public static String decompress(...) {
    ...
    byte[] compressed = response.body.getBytes("UTF-8");
    new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed));
    ...
  }
}
```

(Code from GZIPCompression[https://stackoverflow.com/a/34305182/132396])

It looks like the compressed data doesn't start from the beginning of the `response.body`, thus this **does not** hold **true**:

```
compressed[0] == (byte) (GZIPInputStream.GZIP_MAGIC)
```

Meaning either the payload sent by the server is corrupted or the client code doesn't do the right thing with it.

I read everything on this topic I could find on the web but nothing could provide a solution so far.

Comment: You've checked that the client side doesn't do automatic decompression?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen yes, it doesn't.