# JsonSyntaxException when using mobile data

Tags: android, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm using `ASP Web API` web service which is hosted on [SmarterAsp.net](https://www.smarterasp.net) to get data in `Json` format to use them in my android application, when I use Wifi everything works fine and the `Json` is received correctly but when I use mobile data I get com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException while parsing the Json received, I checked the received `Json` string with the debugger and it was malformed and here is what i received :

> ��������������RMo�@�+՞)�`�Sڦ9TjeU�)�aX�x\��Ah"�{b�����̾y3OL�G�Y�İ�u²"���r'��J   V�@�����(���
>   ���(N9*4MĜ���Fר��m+
>   ���:�7[�/$`3��z����c�%q*Ha�OA|�x~������G�8���"?,�4���(��y���N��j�L%���?B
>   �?S8�lp���(G�rgH�����P�b9����+5��<�n����w_i�G-,��_؋��uz�K;��|�i������� ��|6s����V[J�<�%3���X�������

And here is the method I'm using in android to send and receive data from the `ASP Web API` web service :

```
public String PostObject(String url, Object obj) throws IOException {
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").create().toJson(obj));
    httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
    HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    String rep = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
    return rep;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **not** malformed. You are accepting `gzip` compressed data by declaring `("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")` in the header.

You can either remove the compression or decompress the data and then use it.

[On how to decompress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351668/compression-and-decompression-of-string-data-in-java)

Comment: but can you explain why the data are compressed only when using mobile data ?

Comment: It's behavior should be same in all case. Are you sure you are calling same method in case of both Wifi and mobile data?