# How to decompress gzip messages from a Kafka source in Flume

Tags: apache-kafka, flume

I have a Flume agent with morphline interceptor that reads from a Kafka source with messages compressed in gzip.

Anyone knows how to decompress these messages before morphline process it?

Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [compression and decompression of string data in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351668/compression-and-decompression-of-string-data-in-java)

Comment: Morphline Interceptor is not written in Java.