# Decompressing a buffer from a SOAP response

Tags: java, compression, gzip, encode

This might be a dumb problem but I'm really not able to figure it out.
I'm making a SOAP request in SoapUI that retrieves me a GZIP compressed buffer for a certain file.
My issue is that I'm not able to decompress the buffer obtained ( I'm not that experienced with java ). The only results that I obtained till now are some random 10-11 characters string ( [B@6d03e736 ) or errors like "not in GZIP format)

The buffer looks like this: "1f8b0800000000000000a58e4d0ac2400c85f78277e811f2e665329975bbae500f2022dd2978ff95715ae82cdcf9415efec823c6710247582d5965c32c65aab0f5fc0a5204c415855e7c190ef61b34710bcdc7486d2bab8a7a4910d022d5e107d211ed345f2f37a103da2ddb1f619ab8acefe7fdb1beb6394998c7dfbde3dcac3acf3f399f3eeae152012e010000"

I've looked in many similar threads and ran only into examples where someone gets a random string that gets compressed and then decompressed ( mostly trough **GZIPInputStream/GZIPOutputStream** ).

```
String stringBuffer = "buffer_from_above";

byte[] buffer = stringBuffer.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1); // also tried UTF-8

System.out.println(decompress(buffer));
```

---

```
public static String decompress(final byte[] compressed) throws IOException {
    final StringBuilder outStr = new StringBuilder();
    if ((compressed == null) || (compressed.length == 0)) {
        return "";
    }
    if (isCompressed(compressed)) {
        final GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed));
        final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gis, "UTF-8"));

        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            outStr.append(line);
        }
    } else {
        outStr.append(compressed);
    }
    return outStr.toString();
}
```

I would highly appreciate if someone is able to give me any tips or any advice for this matter.
Thanks for the time spent and I wish you have a great day!

Decompress function stolen from this thread: [compression and decompression of string data in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351668/compression-and-decompression-of-string-data-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

If that's really the string, then you need to convert the hexadecimal to binary before feeding it to the gzip decoder. See [Convert a string representation of a hex dump to a byte array using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java)

Comment: You da best! Thank you very much, it worked out perfectly from the first try. <3