# ColdFusion alternative for hex2bin function PHP

Tags: php, coldfusion, binary, hex, coldfusion-8

I would like to decode hexadecimal encoded binary string; It will work by using the [hex2bin](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php) function of PHP. But I need the same in ColdFusion.

***PHP***

```
 $key="43480170";

 echo hex2bin($key);
```

**Output : CHp**

I have tried the below code. But this ColdFusion code not giving me the result as I got it in PHP;

***ColdFusion***

```
<cfset key="43480170" />

<cfoutput>#binaryDecode(key, "hex" ).toString()#</cfoutput>
```

**Output** : Different every time when run it.

I need to get the result same as '**CHp**' in ColdFusion also.

Comment: What do you mean 'it is not working'? Do you get an error? Results not what you expected?

Comment: I didnt get the value expected. I meant I am getting a different value in PHP and Coldfusion.

Comment: *Different every time when run it.*  FWIW, that is because calling `toString()` on the byte array returns the class name and [hash code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode%28%29) of the byte array, not the *contents* of the array represented as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the ColdFusion provided function for converting binary representation to string using `toString(xxx)` and not the underlying java function `xxx.toString()` as both will render different result. This sounds strange but it is not, java is hard typed language you cannot simply convert a binary data to a string representation like that, [refer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778/how-do-you-convert-binary-data-to-strings-and-back-in-java). Also, if you would have noticed in your original CF code the output is different every time you run it.

Going back to your problem, you just need to make a little change and it works fine:

```
<cfset key="43480170" />
<cfoutput>#toString(binaryDecode(key, "hex" ))#</cfoutput>
```

You can [run the code here](http://trycf.com/gist/71a7089e6b23377c6768/acf11?theme=monokai) to check the difference in output between the two approaches.

### Update:

Following the useful comment by [@Leigh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104223/leigh) on the recommended way to perform a binary to string conversion using the [`CharsetEncode()`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/CharsetEncode) function, the code would result to:

```
<cfset key="43480170" />
<cfoutput>#CharsetEncode(binaryDecode(key, "hex" ),'utf-8')#</cfoutput>
```

You can check the [updated gist](http://trycf.com/gist/71a7089e6b23377c6768/acf11?theme=monokai) with the changes.

Comment: Side note, the docs recommend using charsetEncode() rather than toString() for new applications

Comment: This is a really useful information, that slipped my mind. I think I am going to update the answer with the same. Thanks a lot @Leigh.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close. This should do the trick.

```
<cfset key="43480170">
<cfoutput>#toString(binaryDecode(key, "hex" ))#</cfoutput>
```

Returns `CHp`