# Simulating ByteArrays using ActionScript 2?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2, arrays

Any replacement for the AS3 [ByteArray](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/flash/utils/ByteArray.html) where you can read **raw binary data** via any medium?

Maybe load a TXT file and access the **characters** byte-by-byte? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

search for **base64** - that's how to do it.

Comment: Yeah lain, you won't believe it, that EXACTLY what I'm doing! See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19893/how-do-you-embed-binary-data-in-xml I JUST found and commented on the question!

Answer (score -1):

"The Socket class enables ActionScript code to make socket connections and to read and write raw binary data. It is similar to XMLSocket but does not dictate the format of the received or transmitted data. "