# mvc model has byte[] data- how to display in view should be simple

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, graphics

I've seen an answer to this in MVC3 "Displaying database image (bytes[]) in Razor/MVC3", but it end using two trips.

Is there an improved way in MVC4/5 using razor? Will WebImage help. I'm learning but a lot of this is over my head

The previous questioner made this observation, I echo it.

" I've yet to see an example of the image being taken from the model/viewmodel and displayed (except my answer using TempData). You'd think it would be a common requirement, but either it's so simple no-one asks or it's so difficult no-one bothers."

My images are small bargraphs.

So in my view the collection is passed in the Model.Lots

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Lots) 
{ <tr>
<td> 
@item.LotName
</td>
<td>
// code here to take @item.TaskImage (a byte array) and show image
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see **"Image to Byte[] harder than thought 2 challenges"** for working answer.

Answer (score 0):

As an example to get things working:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(item.TaskImage)" />
```

This technique uses the [data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). We take the incoming byte array, convert it to [Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538021/why-do-we-use-base64) and put it as the data in the URI.

Comment: Note: I've assumed `png` file format in this example. Change it accordingly or have it be printed dynamically.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it soon. Might I ask if you could help with the answer to the write? mvc ef writing System.Drawing bitmap into EF table. No answer yet. many thanks @Rowan

Comment: Ut ohhh When I pasted your answer I get this message: Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'byte?[]' to 'byte[]'@Rowan

Comment: It's a nullable byte array. Use `item.TaskImage.Value`

Comment: That fixed the error. Still trying to write the data to the TaskImage field.  Might I ask your help with the answer to the write question- mvc ef writing System.Drawing bitmap into EF table.  many thanks @Rowan

Comment: You will have to ask a new question to get that answered.

Comment: It is an active question.@Rowan

Comment: opps When I changed to (item.TaskImage.Value) I now get Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'byte[]'

Comment: see **"Image to Byte[] harder than thought 2 challenges"** for working answer.