# upload .jpg image attachment in mail using AWS SES from node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ses

Below is the code from [https://github.com/andrewpuch/aws-ses-node-js-examples](http://github(How%20to%20use%20aws%20ses))   where there is an example to send and email with attachment,

I have modified the code to fetch a image file from aws s3 and and send it with mail as attachment, when i did it for an text file it work perfectly, but when I have sent an image, in the mail I was not able to see the image since it is corrupted.

when I tried opening with apple photo app it has shown that meta data is missing, also I have added Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 in the header of the mail, when I tried with utf8, utf-8 and UTF-8 in **Content-Transfer-Encoding**in the header I got the below response from aws

```
{
  "message": "Unknown encoding: utf8",
  "code": "InvalidParameterValue",
  "time": "2017-03-14T08:42:43.571Z",
  "requestId": "2e220c33-0892-11e7-8a5a-1114bbc28c3e",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "retryable": false,
  "retryDelay": 29.798455792479217
}
```

My modified code to send an image attachment with mail, I even tried encoding the buffer to utf-8, base-64,wasted enough time on this, no clue why it is corrupted, if some one have done this before, help me

```
// Require objects.
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var aws = require('aws-sdk');

// Edit this with YOUR email address.
var email = "*******@gmail.com";

// Load your AWS credentials and try to instantiate the object.
aws.config.loadFromPath(__dirname + '/config.json');

// Instantiate SES.
var ses = new aws.SES();
var s3 = new aws.S3();

// Verify email addresses.
app.get('/verify', function (req, res) {
    var params = {
        EmailAddress: email
    };

    ses.verifyEmailAddress(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        else {
            res.send(data);
        }
    });
});

// Listing the verified email addresses.
app.get('/list', function (req, res) {
    ses.listVerifiedEmailAddresses(function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        else {
            res.send(data);
        }
    });
});

// Deleting verified email addresses.
app.get('/delete', function (req, res) {
    var params = {
        EmailAddress: email
    };

    ses.deleteVerifiedEmailAddress(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        else {
            res.send(data);
        }
    });
});

// Sending RAW email including an attachment.
app.get('/send', function (req, res) {
    var params = { Bucket: 's3mailattachments', Key: 'aadhar.jpg' };
    var attachmentData;
    s3.getObject(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else {
            console.log(data.ContentLength);
            console.log(data.ContentType);
            console.log(data.Body);
            var ses_mail = "From: 'AWS Tutorial Series' <" + email + ">\n";
            ses_mail = ses_mail + "To: " + email + "\n";
            ses_mail = ses_mail + "Subject: AWS SES Attachment Example\n";
            ses_mail = ses_mail + "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
            ses_mail = ses_mail + "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"NextPart\"\n\n";
            ses_mail = ses_mail + "--NextPart\n";
            ses_mail = ses_mail + "Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii\n\n";
            ses_mail = ses_mail + "This is the body of the email.\n\n";
            ses_mail = ses_mail + "--NextPart\n";
            ses_mail = ses_mail + "Content-Type: image/jpeg; \n";
            ses_mail = ses_mail + "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"aadhar.jpg\"\n";
            ses_mail = ses_mail + "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n"
            ses_mail = ses_mail + data.Body;
            ses_mail = ses_mail + "--NextPart";


            var params = {
                RawMessage: { Data: new Buffer(ses_mail) },
                Destinations: [email],
                Source: "'AWS Tutorial Series' <" + email + ">'"
            };

            ses.sendRawEmail(params, function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                }
                else {
                    res.send(data);
                }
            });

        }
    });
});

// Start server.
var server = app.listen(3003, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log('AWS SES example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Comment: A minor improvement - `new Buffer(string)` is now deprecated, therefore the code where it is used could be replaced with `Buffer.from(string)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, your MIME message is not well formatted. The last line should be `--NextPart--` instead of just `--NextPart`.

You should also convert the `data.Body` array into its base64 string representation using `Buffer.from(data.Body).toString('base64')` as shown below:

```
var ses_mail = "From: 'AWS Tutorial Series' <" + email + ">\n";
ses_mail += "To: " + email + "\n";
ses_mail += "Subject: AWS SES Attachment Example\n";
ses_mail += "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
ses_mail += "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"NextPart\"\n\n";
ses_mail += "--NextPart\n";
ses_mail += "Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii\n\n";
ses_mail += "This is the body of the email.\n\n";
ses_mail += "--NextPart\n";
ses_mail += "Content-Type: image/jpeg; \n";
ses_mail += "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"aadhar.jpg\"\n";
ses_mail += "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n"
ses_mail += Buffer.from(data.Body).toString('base64');
ses_mail += "--NextPart--";
```

Then, you can pass the `ses_mail` string as raw message data as `RawMessage: { Data: ses_mail }` instead of `RawMessage: { Data: new Buffer(ses_mail) }`.

Comment: +1, great job, can you please mention why should i use only base64 not others, its good even if you explain the things in low level, I am not able to wrap the encoding stuff around my head

Comment: Because we need the string representation for the image data that will be concatenated with your `ses_mail` string variable. I think you'd be interested in reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538021/why-do-we-use-base64).

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this problem is to pass your nodemailer MailOptions parameter (inline image attachments **cid:aadhar** and all) into the nodemailer composer producing for you a buffer data like so:

```
import MailComposer from 'nodemailer/lib/mail-composer';

new MailComposer( mailOptions )
    .compile()
    .build(( err, Data ) => {
        if( err !== null ) {
            process.stderr.write( err ); // for example
            return;
        }
        ses.sendRawEmail({
            RawMessage: {
                Data
            }
        });
    });
```

Ps: I'm using the clunky `callback` technique to minimize complexity in the answer. Feel free to wrap the build call in a promise and *async/wait* your buffer data which you can then pass to your `ses.sendRawEmail` method separately.