# How come I have to convert file to base64 before sending to client?

Tags: node.js, ajax

I have an ajax endpoint where I generate a pdf based off the user's `GET` request, then send them back the pdf through a Buffer.

When I try to send them the buffer directly, the resulting downloaded pdf is corrupted, however, when I send them a base64 version then decode it on the client side it works properly.

**AJAX endpoint:**

```
module.exports = function(req, res) {
     pdf.create('<h1>Title</h1>').toBuffer(function(err, buffer)  {
          res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
          res.send(buffer.toString('base64'));
      });
};
```

**Client:**

```
$.get('/createPDF', (data) => {
    var len = binary.length;
    var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(len);
    var view = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        view[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    const blob = new Blob([view], {type: "application/pdf"});
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf');
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
 });
```

If I skip the `toString('base64')` on the server and the part above the `Blob` creation on the client it doesn't work, but if I include that it does. Does anyone know why this might be the case? Note I'm asking for this specific use-case of jquery's ajax.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: That‘s looks strange, could tell me what pdf package you used? I want do a research

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we use Base64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538021/why-do-we-use-base64)

Comment: @sinbar its called html-pdf https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf