# How to convert canvas json to base64image?

Tags: node.js, canvas, fonts, fabricjs

This functionality I need in server side(nodejs)

I have installed canvas 2.2.0 version and in this I m unable to use loadFromJSON function.

But when I am using fabric and its canvas then this working fine.

I have changed from Fabric canvas to canvas because unable to change/set custom font in that

With the canvas 2.2.0 version, I am able to change or set custom fonts. But now I am anable to convert json data to base64image.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: base64 is not an image format. An image is converted to base64 format before sending ti to a server for example. Which mean you already should have an image in some format like bmp or jpg. Adding link for reference. It is a very good discussion:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538021/why-do-we-use-base64

Comment: I have image data in json object.

Comment: After using canvas 2.2.0 unable to use loadFromJSON

Comment: @VIKASKOHLI any error?

Comment: loadFromJSON is not a function in canvas 2.2.0 that I already mentioned

Comment: `loadFromJSON` is a fabricjs function, not canvas 2.2.0

Comment: Then how can I achieve this thing in canvas 2.2.0 so that I convert fro json to image