# Correct way to pass base64 info in URL as query string?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web, server

I am sending some parameters in query string by converting them in `base64` using method `btoa()`. I just want to know, do I still need to wrap the result into the `encodeURI` method to pass on the correct information to the server in URL.

For example:

- `http://example.com/{name}` - **For this, which one is correct from below?**
- `"http://example.com/" + btoa("some-name")`
- `"http://example.com/" + encodeURI(btoa("some-name"))`

Comment: Does my answer clarify your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to transform your string to Base 64. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743160/how-do-i-encode-and-decode-a-base64-string) for C#:

```
  var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
  return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
```

You can also read [the reason why we use Base 64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538021/why-do-we-use-base64).

No need to use a method such as `encodeURI` after, it would be useless because all the characters for Base 64 (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, =, +) [are not escaped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI):

> encodeURI escapes all characters except:
>
> ```
> A-Z a-z 0-9 ; , / ? : @ & = + $ - _ . ! ~ * ' ( ) #
> ```

By the way, `encodeURI` and `btoa` are about JavaScript, not asp.net as you mention in tags.