# image pixel values storage in XML using Matlab

Tags: xml, matlab, pixel, store

I'm currently working on storing pixels in XML format using Matlab. The problem is that I have no idea about data storage under XML. Can any expert please give me some guidelines? Any relevant materials are welcome and appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/98/07/binary/binary.html) a start for your research.  It's a bit old so you'll want to read more up-to-date information, but it's not a bad introduction.

You might also look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19893/how-do-you-embed-binary-data-in-xml) which cover some of what you are concerned with.