# Embed image in file

Tags: c#, xml, image, file, embed

I'm trying to figure out a way to embed an image into a file in c#.

What I'm doing is to create a file with text inside of it (it uses XML) , and I want a quite big image embedded into it which I then can read from the file along with the XML.

But how do I do that?

I can't put an image file along with the file since the file may be used on different computers and I don't want 100's of image files laying around with the files.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: It does not smell nice, tt's not a good idea normally to place binary inside XML, but... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19893/how-do-you-embed-binary-data-in-xml

Comment: @leonbloy. Isn't it what Microsoft Word doing when you put image on the page?

Comment: @leonbloy Thanks! I'll try it at least. But why isn't it a good idea? What can go wrong by doing this?

Comment: Embed the file as base64 in the xml stream.