# Convert files uploaded in database into cdata in an xml file with ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, paperclip, nokogiri, cdata

I store my files in a `document table` with `paperclip`.My files are `word,csv,xlsx` and `pdf`.
I want to read these records from database and convert them into `cdata` and put them in an xml tag named `Attachment`.

This is the out put I'm looking forward:

```
<Attachment ContentType="xlsx" Extension="xlsx" Description="TEST2.xlsx"><![CDATA[UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQBxDjkrcAEAAKAFAAATANsBW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbCCi1wEooAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA..
```

and my files are like this when I query them:

```
#<Paperclip::Attachment:0x000000049dfe28 @name=:picture, @name_string="picture", @instance=#<Document id: 225, picture_file_name: "data", picture_content_type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.word...", picture_file_size: 10001, picture_updated_at: "2018-02-07 20:14:18", ece_id: 242, created_at: "2018-02-07 20:14:18", updated_at: "2018-02-07 20:14:18", xml_file_name: nil, xml_content_type: nil, xml_file_size: nil, xml_updated_at: nil, whodunnit: nil, document_type: "Attachment">, @options={:convert_options=>{}, :default_style=>:original, :default_url=>"/:attachment/:style/missing.png", :escape_url=>true, :restricted_characters=>/[&$+,\/:;=?@<>\[\]\{\}\|\\\^~%# ]/, :filename_cleaner=>nil, :hash_data=>":class/:attachment/:id/:style/:updated_at", :hash_digest=>"SHA1", :interpolator=>Paperclip::Interpolations, :only_process=>[], :path=>":rails_root/public:url", :preserve_files=>false, :processors=>[:thumbnail], :source_file_options=>{}, :storage=>:filesystem, :styles=>{}, :url=>"/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename", :url_generator=>Paperclip::UrlGenerator, :use_default_time_zone=>true, :use_timestamp=>true, :whiny=>true, :validate_media_type=>true, :check_validity_before_processing=>true}, @post_processing=true, @queued_for_delete=[], @queued_for_write={}, @errors={}, @dirty=false, @interpolator=Paperclip::Interpolations, @url_generator=#<Paperclip::UrlGenerator:0x000000049dfd10 @attachment=#<Paperclip::Attachment:0x000000049dfe28 ...>>, @source_file_options={}, @whiny=true>
```

I'm using `nokogiri` to generate the xml  tags.

Do you have any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: What specific problem are you facing? are you having difficulty reading the file or generating the XML document?

Comment: I don't know how to put my files like pdf or word in an xml file @TamerShlash

Comment: I assume the purpose is just data transfer, you do not intend to _embed_ the pdf/word file and be able to view it inside the XML file, right?

Comment: Yeah ! But i have to convert it into some code !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the file content with Paperclip like this:

```
file_content = Paperclip.io_adapters.for(attachment.file).read
```

There are many ways to write a `CDATA` XML tag to your XML document with Nokogiri, depending on the way your are building your document, here's one from the [cheat sheet](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/Cheat-sheet):

```
doc.create_cdata(file_content)
```

However, you should encode the file content with base64 encoding, because the file content is binary, and it might have characters that are not allowed in XML documents.

So here it is:

```
require 'base64' # if not already required
Base64.encode64(file_content)
```

All together, here's a pseudo snippet:

```
file_content = Paperclip.io_adapters.for(attachment.file).read
doc.create_cdata(Base64.encode64(file_content))
```

You should also consider using `Base64` element instead of `CDATA`, checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19904/368167) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20646/368167) answers (and other on the same question).